# combine two list of pojos into another list of pojo on the basis of specific value using java 8

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, pojo

I am trying to enhance my current code using java 8

I have two list of pojos

```
    class A{
    long id;
    String name;
    Sting age;
// getters setters
    }

    class B{
    long id;
    String address;
    String city;
// getters setters
    }
```

required class:

```
    class C{
    long id;
    String name;
    Sting age;
    String address;
    String city;
// getters setters
    }
```

i have `list<A>` and `List<B>`, and require final `List<C>`. I have completed this using for loops and everything. but i now want to streamline in using java 8 functionalitis.

Any help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
 List<C> cList=new ArrayList<>();
    C obj=new C();
    for(A aa: aList){
    C obj=new C();
     obj.setId(a.getId);
     obj.setName(a.getName);
     obj.setAge(a.getAge);
       for(B bb: bList){
         if(aa.getId==bb.getId(){
           obj.setAddress(bb.setAddress);
           obj.setCity(bb.setCity);
          }
       } 
       cList.add(obj); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your loops so we can help you turn it into something that works with Java 8?

Comment: @ShanS i have added my exisiting code for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want just transfer your code to streams, you can:

```java
List<C> collect = aList.stream()
        .map(a -> {
            C obj = new C();
            obj.setId(a.getId());
            obj.setName(a.getName());
            obj.setAge(a.getAge());
            bList.stream()
                    .filter(b -> a.getId() == b.getId())
                    .findFirst()
                    .ifPresent(b -> {
                        obj.setAddress(b.getAddress());
                        obj.setCity(b.getCity());
                    });
            return obj;
        }).collect(toList());
```

But it will be better to introduce map for `bList` and use it as a lookup latter.

```
Map<Long, B> map = bList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(B::getId, b -> b));

List<C> collect = aList.stream()
        .map(a -> {
            C obj = new C();
            obj.setId(a.getId());
            obj.setName(a.getName());
            obj.setAge(a.getAge());
            if (map.containsKey(a.getId())) {
                B b = map.get(a.getId());
                obj.setAddress(b.getAddress());
                obj.setCity(b.getCity());
            }
            return obj;
        }).collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way I can think of is to use a `HashMap` instead of a `List`, then use `Id` as a key and the actual object as a value, gives you an easier lookup. Also generate a full constructor for `C`:

```
A a1 = new A(1234, "foo", "bar");
A a2 = new A(12347, "baz", "quux");
B b1 = new B(2345, "example street", "city");
B b2 = new B(1234, "test street", "town");

HashMap<Long, A> aHashMap = new HashMap<Long, A>();
HashMap<Long, B> bHashMap = new HashMap<Long, B>();

aHashMap.put(a1.getId(), a1);
aHashMap.put(a2.getId(), a2);

bHashMap.put(b1.getId(), b1);
bHashMap.put(b2.getId(), b2);

List<C> cList = aHashMap.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry->bHashMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
        .map(entry -> {
            B matchingB = bHashMap.get(entry.getKey());
            return new C(entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue().getName(),
                    entry.getValue().getAge(),
                    matchingB.getAddress(),
                    matchingB.getCity());
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(cList.toString());
```

Returns (I changed `toString()`):

```
[C{id=1234, name='foo', age='bar', address='test street', city='town'}]
```

Comment: thanks for response, in the mentioned solution I will have to add extra code in order to convert list into hashmap as I am getting list<objects> from jdbcTemplate.query(String,rowMapper), but sure i can give it a try

Comment: You can just use the `Map<Long, B> map = bList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(B::getId, b -> b));` snippet mentioned in lczapski's answer to get the maps.